How to compile Qt lupdate with clang-based parser via MSVC?
I work on Windows 11 with CMake 3.29 and MSVC from Visual Studio 2022.
I want to compile Qt 6.7 with LLVM 18. The Qt Linguist TS-Update Tool lupdate should support the clang-based parser. I compile Qt 6.7 and LLVM 18 myself via MSVC.
I've read the Qt Wiki:

https://wiki.qt.io/Lupdate_clang-based_c%2B%2B_parser

It tells me that I need to build LLVM with CLANG_LINK_CLANG_DYLIB=ON.
I build LLVM with:
cmake -GNinja \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang;clang-tools-extra;compiler-rt;lld;lldb \
    -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86;AArch64 \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_EH=ON \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON \
    -DCLANG_LINK_CLANG_DYLIB=ON

The LLVM CMake configuration gives me the error:

Cannot set CLANG_LINK_CLANG_DYLIB=ON when LLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=OFF

Unfortunately, setting LLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB to ON is ignored when building with MSVC on Windows. It is set to OFF in the LLVM CMake code:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/d751e407def4e1540ae0af12a179ce4f2a8f676c/llvm/CMakeLists.txt#L820C1-L820C33

If I build LLVM without CLANG_LINK_CLANG_DYLIB=ON, Qt's lupdate will list the option in its help. However, it still doesn't support the clang-based parser:
> lupdate --help
[...]
    -clang-parser [compilation-database-dir]
           Use clang to parse cpp files. Otherwise a custom parser is used.
[...]
> lupdate -clang-parser
Unrecognized option '-clang-parser'.

Is there a way to build lupdate with the clang-based parser via MSVC on Windows?
